# Conflict between Fancybox and Isotope filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope Filtering using the following code:

```
// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#filters a').click(function(){
var $container = $('#container');

  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
```

And I also am using Fancy box v1.3.4 with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.fancyframe").fancybox();
});
```

The problem is that the Isotope filter works until you open a fancybox, one you then close the fancy box if you try to click on a filter it does not work, nothing is changed and I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope'
```

What is the problem here, how do I stop them from conflicting

Comment: I hope both `.facnybox()` and `.click()` are inside the `.ready()` method (apparently not in your code above)

Comment: @JFK Hi, I am not sure what you mean by that, if you can post that as an answer showing me how it should be then I will try it out

Comment: I meant `$(document).ready(function(){ // fancybox AND click/isotpe code here });` ... in your code above you only showed fancybox inside of the `ready` method. I am not sure if this is the reason of your issue.

Comment: @JFK The isotope code that I have posted is part of a bigger block which is inside of another `$(document).ready(function(){`. So both fancybox and isotope are within `ready` methods, but not the same method, is this a problem?

Comment: is not a problem, it's just redundant. the only way for me to figure out what would be the problem is with a link or a test page or jsfiddle because it could be something else but your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two elements with the id 'container' in your html page after the fancybox is opened. But IDs must be unique throughout your page.

I suppose you cannot choose a different id for the fancybox, so try to rename the other id.

Comment: I have just double checked and I do not have multiple id's named container. Not even in the fancybox popup.

Comment: You have to give more info then. Do you have a link to a page where we can see?